# Read and extract attributes from wordpress video shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, attributes, extract, shortcode

My purpose is to go from something like this, as taken from `post_content`:

```
[video width="1080" height="1920" webm="http://path/file.webm" autoplay="true"][/video]
```

to an array like this:

```
Array( 
    width=>1080, 
    height=>1920,
    webm=>"http://path/file.webm",
    autoplay=>"true"
);
```

Of course with more or less pairs depending on what the user has entered in the video shortcode.

I have read the Shortcode_API and the [instructions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) about `shortcode_atts`. Nowhere I can find an easy explanation on how to get those attributes in a form of an array.

Despite what people keep suggesting I *cannot* use `shortcode_atts` because this wordpress function requires the attributes to be *already in an array*!

I know how to get the above more or less done with regex. But is there any wordpress obvious way to turn shortcode attributes into an array? I know there should be.

As an example, this doesn't work:

```
shortcode_atts( array(
                'width'    => '640',
                'height'   => '360',
                'mp4'   => '',
                'autoplay' => '',
                'poster'   => '',
                'src'      => '',
                'loop'     => '',
                'preload'  => 'metadata',
                'webm'   => '',
        ), $atts);
```

because $atts is supposed to be an array, but all I have is a string from `$post_content` which looks like this:

```
[video width="1080" height="1920" webm="http://path/file.webm" autoplay="true"][/video]
```

Please note: I am not implementing a shortcode functionality or anything like that. I just need to *read* a wordpress video shortcode as added in post content.

Comment: If you want a generic solutions to handling shortcodes of any kind, look at my library: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone's interested the answer to the above is the function `shortcode_parse_atts` as described [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_parse_atts/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very compact solution with a regular expression:

### Code

```
<?php
    $input = '[video width="1080" height="1920" webm="http://path/file.webm" autoplay="true"][/video]';

    preg_match_all('/([A-Za-z-_0-9]*?)=[\'"]{0,1}(.*?)[\'"]{0,1}[\s|\]]/', $input, $regs, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $result = array();
    for ($mx = 0; $mx < count($regs); $mx++) {
        $result[$regs[$mx][1]] = is_numeric($regs[$mx][2]) ? $regs[$mx][2] : '"'.$regs[$mx][2].'"';
    } 

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

### Result

`Array
    [width] => 1080
    [height] => 1920
    [webm] => "http://path/file.webm"
    [autoplay] => "true"
)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that (at least in version 4.7) that the function you specify with add_shortcode() will put the shortcode parameters into an array:

If you add the shortcode like this:

```
    add_shortcode('my_shortcode_name', 'my_shortcode_function');
```

Then the 'my_shortcode_function' like this will have an array of the attributes:

```
function my_shortcode_function($atts) {
// this will print the shortcode's attribute array
echo '<pre>';print_r($atts);echo '</pre>';
}
```

...Rick...